# How is the execution time defined in Azure Functions (Consumption Plan)?

Tags: azure-functions

The [Consumption Plan Cost Billing FAQ](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Consumption-Plan-Cost-Billing-FAQ#am-i-billed-for-await-time-) states that you are billed for "await" time even if the process is just idle waiting for some I/O-event.

So

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

is billed, but what impact does the following have on the cost of running the function?

```
var _ = Task.Delay(10000);
```

(Of course, Task.Delay is just an example of some background task whose value is not relevant for the return value of the function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of how Azure Functions operate is that it isn't recommended / doesn't support the ability to manage background threads. So with this in mind I would expect the function to complete as soon as the assignment has been executed and then the Task to affectively be cancelled / terminiated.

It might be worth looking at this in the Azure docs as it covers off [running background processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs)

An additional resource worth looking at would be [Durable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview) and on [Azure Fridays](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-friday-durable-functions-in-azure-functions/)

Durable functions will handle some of the complexity of putting messages on and off a queue for you and the best bit is that while the background activities are happening there isn't a charge on the entry point function.

Hope this helps.